# is this the proper identification of this cyclic molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image]

Attempt:

(1*S*,3*S*)-1,3-Dichlorocyclohexane

I'm just not sure about the nomenclature for R and S configurations (our teacher was a little unclear). I gave it my best shot after looking through some textbooks but would like just a quick confirmation or someone to tell me if it's wrong.

In addition, if I exchanged the positions of the Cl and H groups on each side with each other would I get an enantiomer? ((1*R*,3*R*)-1,3-Dichlorocyclohexane)

Comment: Correct and yes.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, as already mentioned in a comment.

Some might find more or less helpful to redraw the structure to:

[image: Fig.1 rational skeletal formula]

Your additional question can be tricky, understood a different way. It's possible to exchange H and Cl positions, or rather axial to equatorial bonds and the other way around – by switching to the other boat conformation, i.e. without changing the configuration:

[image: Fig.2 boat conformation switch]

(The two structures are identical, one of them can be rotated to superimpose the other.)